# Conditionally render or prop for modal render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a little question about some techniques that are used to render/not render modals.

At the moment there are 2 main ways to do so.

For the first example, we use a visible prop onto the modal and based on that, we will apply a style that will hide the modal. This will be handled by state and then toggled with a button for example :

```
<Modal
   title="Foo"
   visible={this.state.visible}
 >
   Foo
</Modal>
```

The second way of doing also use state, but uses a condition to render the modal or not :

```
{this.state.visible && (
   <Modal title="Foo">
      Foo
   </Modal>
)}
```

The handy thing with this is that the modal will not be rendered until it should.

So what is the best way of doing? I suppose the 2 are right but is there one that is better than the other?

Comment: Former may generate the output while the latter won't. Define "better" please. It all depends upon one's particular use case. It's like asking what's better: a truck or a regular car.

Comment: By better I mean good practise. I suppose it's better to have the second one because it's only redered when it really should, but I don't really know if that's an issue

Comment: @Trisma I added Modal component that antd use. So you can see best practices with more than 286 commits for modal component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally second one is better, because by checking the state at Parent Component, you separate Parent Component logic and Child Component logic, since Modal component only responsible for showing the modal, but the logic whether open or close modal belongs to Parent Component logic. But both solutions will work :)

Comment: That is what I was thinking. Beside moving the logic away, would there be any performance difference?

Comment: I think it is also better for performance wise, because you do not render the Modal the component  in the first opening, but render when needed

Comment: And what about returning a null like @zemil is explaining? It's kind of the same but cleans up the parent code I suppose

Comment: Yes you can check the visible prop and return null if false, both will work but this way your modal component will be cleaned from if else checks, just shows the modal, if you put logic inside the modal maybe you cannot use it across the application(i.e it will not be reusable)

Answer (score 0):

Just research the question in UI libs docs: antd, material-ui, semantic-ui.

And you will find the answer => prop (with names open, show, visible etc.) is the best way to control visibility (inner state of component).

> For example you can see antd modal that use this package
>   (react-component/dialog):
>   https://github.com/react-component/dialog/blob/master/src/Dialog.tsx

You can return null or use css (display: none; for sample) for invisible modal

Comment: Why is it the best way then? I don't think that because some libs are doing it that it's the most efficient way

Comment: @Trisma, because this approach encapsulates logic inside single component (modal in your situation) and you don't need to keep in mind outside logic

Comment: But what if you take this position : the view logic of the modal should be in the parent (just for the render) as of @onuriltan

Comment: yeah of course, state can be outside (redux, mobx, parent state etc.) component but in your case you want to control View(render) logic not state so I recommend you to encapsulate view logic inside component

Comment: So that means that the component will still be rendered even if it's not used

Comment: You can return null inside modal. I guess UI libs above use this approach

Comment: That's interesting indeed. It will cleanup the parent component and will not influence performance on a measurable scale. But display: none will still load the component itself, I would opt for a return null

Comment: It's true. E.g. material-ui's ModalUnstyled returns null if it is not open, but also... the ModalUnstyled shouldn't have any transition (see `!hasTransition` in https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui-unstyled/src/ModalUnstyled/ModalUnstyled.js). With it it doesn't return null. Still, transitions are one of the reason for me why I think will stick with logic inside single component and using `open` prop.